# 25 concurrent async WCF calls to orchestrate using Tasks

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0, task

I have an application (.NET 4.0) that loads administrative data on startup. I have to make 25 concurrent async WCF calls, some of them are quick (40ms), some others take longer to execute, up to 882 ms. I plan to store the data locally, but for the very first application startup, it needs to be done quickly as possible.

It should be noted that the proxies are in a library targetting .NET 3.5 and are internally using BeginXxx and EndXxx methods pattern wrapped into an async method whith the help of Jeffrey Richter's Async Enumerator.

The WCF channel factories for each client proxy that will be used are opened before launching the calls.

At this time, I'm using Task.Factory.StartNew with an action that launch each async call. The experience is the following :

1. All BeginXXX calls are all sent.
2. The program seems to work outside of my code for at least 10 seconds.
3. Finally all the EndXXX calls are sent to retreive the results.

I'm wondering why such a delay occurs. My computer has 4 core, If the number of concurrent calls are limited to 4, there is no delay at all, as soon as I add another call, a delay is experienced.

Any help appreciated.

**EDIT 1** : The binding used is netTcpBinding.

Server configuration is following :

```
     <netTcpBinding>
        <binding transactionFlow="true" listenBacklog="500" maxReceivedMessageSize="400000"
    portSharingEnabled="false">
         <readerQuotas maxDepth="200" />
         <reliableSession enabled="false" />
         <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" protectionLevel="None" />
            <message clientCredentialType="None" />
         </security>
        </binding>
     </netTcpBinding>

<service name="AdminService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
     contract="IAdmin">
         <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
         </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
     contract="IMetadataExchange" />
     </service>
```

**EDIT 2**: Following are the default throttling values set by the WCF 4.5 runtime on a 4 Core machine.

```
ListenBacklog is [500]
MaxConnections is [48]
MaxConcurrentCalls is [64]
MaxConcurrentInstances is [2147483647]
MaxConcurrentSessions is [400]
```

**EDIT 3** : Here is the code using J.Richter's AsyncEnumerator :

```
       private IEnumerator<int> DoWorkGetXXXX(AsyncEnumerator<MyResult> ae)
        {
            ae.ThrowOnMissingDiscardGroup(true);

            IClientChannel proxy = (IClientChannel)CreateChannel(_bindingName);

            bool success = false;
            try
            {
                proxy.Open();
                // The call to BeginXXX goes here
                ((IAcaccount)proxy).BeginGetXXX(..., ae.EndVoid(0, DiscardGetXXX), proxy);
                //
                yield return 1;

                if (ae.IsCanceled())
                {
                    goto Complete;
                }
                // Iterator was not canceled, process should continue.

                // The call to EndXXX goes here
                IAsyncResult ar = ae.DequeueAsyncResult();
                try
                {
                    ae.Result = ((IAcaccount)ar.AsyncState).EndGetXXX(ar);
                    proxy.Close();
                    success = true;
                }
                // In the mean time, we catch and rethrow :)
                // If this exception occurs, we should retry a call to the service
                catch (FaultException<AppFabricCachingException> retry)
                {
                }
                // fatal Exception in data service, administrator action required...
                catch (FaultException<EFExecutionException> fatal)
                {
                }
                catch (FaultException<EFUpdateException> fatal)
                {
                }
                catch (FaultException<EFNoRowException> nr)
                {
                }
                catch (FaultException fe)
                {
                }
                catch (ServiceActivationException sae)
                {
                }
                catch (CommunicationException ce)
                {
                }
                //

            }
            finally
            {
                // If an error occurred, abort the proxy.
                if (!success)
                {
                    proxy.Abort();
                }
            }


    // End of operations.
        Complete:
            proxy = null;
        }
```

Comment: this might help, it could be a connection issue http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxnetcom/thread/1f863f20-09f9-49a5-8eee-17a89b591007

Comment: What is your binding? Server configuration? Can you post server config?

Comment: @JohnField I've edited my question, I'm using netTcpBinding.

Comment: @evgenyl I've edited my question with the requested information.

Comment: did you try to enlarge Throttling values?

Comment: check out this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee377061(v=bts.10).aspx I think it's worth it giving a shot  to implement a service throttling behaviour

Comment: @evgenyl : I've not played with throttling values because the service is processing at least 22 requests concurrently yet.

Comment: @JohnField : I've edited my question to include default throttling values set by the WCF runtime. This seems OK.

Comment: Using `StartNew` to invoke APM methods (like BeginXXX) isn't very efficient.  You should simply invoke the BeginXXX methods or wrap the APM in a Task.  See `TaskFactory.FromAsync`

Comment: It's unclear how you're making those calls. Does each Task just call `BeginXXX` and then exit? Or does it wait for the response and call `EndXXX`? Show us the code that actually makes the requests and reads the responses.

Comment: @JimMischel : The Task call BeginXXX, wait for the response (yield return in the AsyncEnumerator) and then call EndXXX.

Comment: @PeterRitchie : I'll try to rewrite a new proxy DLL as suggested to see if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to play with the value of serviceThrottling, as well as maxItemsInObjectGraph, maxBufferSize, MaxBufferPoolSize (i have them set to int.MaxValue).